# Complex circulant matrices

Tags: matrices

Can someone please show my why a matrix is normal if it is made diagonal by a unitary similarity transformation?

I know that a complex matrix is normal when it commutes with its conjugate transpose, but I am lost on how to do this problem. I suspect I need to do some sort of decomposition by finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but I am not quite sure because I am having trouble finding online material on similarity transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A=UDU^*$. Then $A^*=U^{**}D^*U^* = UD^*U^*$, and since diagonal matrices always commute we have
$$ AA^* = UDU^*UD^*U^* = UDD^*U^* = UD^*DU^* = UD^*U^*UDU^* = A^*A $$

Comment: Is UDU* the format for an orthogonal similarity transformation matrix?

Comment: @thepillsbury: Depending on which source you're following it may also be $U^*DU$, but the difference is immaterial here, because $U^*$ is unitary iff $U$ is.

Comment: So, what exactly is a unitary similarity transformation? Is it the same as Jordan canonical form?

Comment: @thepillsbury: A similarity transformation is just the map $A\mapsto P^{-1}AP$ for some invertible $P$, which takes one square matrix and produces another square matrix (which represents the same linear map from a vector space to itself in a different basis). When $P$ happens to be unitary (i.e. $P^{-1}=P^*$) that word is used about the transformation too.

Comment: Really, if you don't know what "unitary similarity transformation" means, you ought to ***say so in your question*** from the beginning, instead of just using the term in the question text as if it already means something to you. Otherwise you will get answers that assume you know _what_ you're talking about and just need help _reasoning_ about it.

Comment: I'm sorry..I've been really struggling in this linear algebra class and I was afraid people would downvote it.. I will be more clear about what I know in my next posts. Thank you.